# $C^1(\bar \Omega)$ is a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

My professor gave a proof of the completeness of $(C^1(\bar \Omega),\|\cdot \|_{C^1})$ based on the fundamental theorem of calculus. I though about an alternative and I would like to know whether this is formally correct:

Assuming completeness of $(C^0(\bar \Omega),\|\cdot \|_{C^0})$ is known, we want to show that, given a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)_n \subset C^1(\bar \Omega)$ there is a function $f \in C^1(\bar \Omega)$ s.t. $f_n \to f$ in the $C^1$-norm, i.e. $ \| f_n - f \|_{C^1} \to 0$.

Knowing that

$$ \| f \|_{C^1} \triangleq \| f \|_{C^0} + \| f' \|_{C^0}$$

where $f'$ is the first derivative of $f$. It is immediate to show that

$$ (f_n)_n \text{ is Cauchy in } C^1(\bar \Omega) \Longrightarrow (f_n)_n,(f_n')_n \text{ are Cauchy in } C^0(\bar \Omega)$$

By completeness of $C^0(\bar \Omega)$ there are $f,g \in C^0(\bar \Omega)$ s.t. $f_n \xrightarrow{C^0} f, ~ f_n' \xrightarrow{C^0} g$. To conclude we need to show that $f'=g$. I would now argue as:

$$ \sup_{x \in \bar \Omega} \bigg|\lim_{h \to 0} \bigg(\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} -\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f_n(x+h) - f_n(x)}{h} \bigg) \bigg| = \\
\sup_{x \in \bar \Omega}~ \lim_{h \to 0}~ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{h} \bigg| f(x+h) - f(x)- f_n(x+h) + f_n(x)\bigg| \le \\
\sup_{x \in \bar \Omega}~ \lim_{h \to 0}~ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{h} \bigg| f(x+h) - f_n(x+h)\bigg| + \bigg|f_n(x)- f(x)\bigg| = 0$$

as, by hyp

$$ \sup_{x \in \bar \Omega} |f(x) - f_n(x)| \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$$

so this holds in particular for any $x \in \bar \Omega$.

My doubts are about the last claim, where I conclude that $\sup (…) = 0$, I fear I am messing with $\sup \lim$ vs $\lim \sup$ and that the last step is not legitimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the last step is legitimate or not, because you're simply not proving what needs to be proved. As you point out, you need to show that $f'=g$. But there's no $g$ anywhere in your supposed proof of this!

There's no $g$ *visible*. There's also no implicit hidden $g$. By definition $g=\lim_nf_n'$, and there's also no $f_n'$ in the proof. No, there's no $f_n'$ in the display $$\lim_{h\to0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}.$$That's the derivative of $\lim_n f_n$, not the derivative of $f_n$.

In fact all you've proved here is this: $$\lim_{h\to0}0=0.$$Because the thing on the inside of the $\lim_h$ on the first line is $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}=0.$$So you're taking the limit of $0$ as $h$ tends to $0$. Doesn't prove anything about $f'$.

How *do* you prove $f'=g$? The only thing that springs to  mind is an argument using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus...